# How to get database values to shown on HTML select-option?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I believe its a pretty simple question, yet I couldn't find the answer for it. Problem is I cant get the values that I've entered to a table on my DB in phpmyadmin to be shown on the drop-down list in the HTML.

this is the entire form that supposed to take the name of the album and show it on the drop-down select

---

```
<h3>Upload Music</h3>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    Song Name: <br/>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <br/><br/>
    Select Album : <br/>
    <select>
        <?php
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT 'Id','name' FROM 'albumssss'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $album_id = $row['Id'];
            $album_name = $row['name'];
            echo "<option value='$album_id'>$album_name</option>";
           }
        ?>
    </select>

    <br/><br/>
    Select Song : <br/><br/>
    <input type="file" name="song"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload"/>
    <br/>
</form>
```

---

Values on the DB table 'albumssss' are only 'Id' and 'name'. Id is AI and name is whatever the user wanna enter when he creates a new album in a different form.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Check your table, maybe the table is empty... And why `albumssss` for table name???

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that doing it the way you are, you will do nothing but print a string (x) number of times.  You need to generate the string with the value:

```
echo "<option value='". $album_id. "'>". $album_name ."</option>";
```

Comment: Thanks,but im still getting nothing in the select drop-down.
this all thing is pretty weird since im basically using a working template from my teacher which uses the same code and does works

Comment: Are you sure your table is populated?  Have you tried just echoing the result completely to verify that you are getting data?  I don't see an error check on where you're pulling you data.  Are you sure there is no error?

Comment: What do you mean populated? that there are values in the table?
then,yes there is.
I know there isnt any error checking since its a really basic code,ill probably add it later on.
how can I echo it to see if im getting any data?

Comment: Skipping that part for now, you are using a mysql call which is deprecated.  mysqli is the new way to do it.  The exact code block you have there may work for your professor because HIS server still supports it.  Yours may not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3>Upload Music</h3>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
Song Name: <br/>
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<br/><br/>
Select Album : <br/>
<select>
    <?php
    $sql ="SELECT Id,name FROM albumssss";
    //echo $sql;
    $query=mysql_query($sql);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($query))
    {?>
    <option value="<?=$row[0]?>"><?=$row[1]?></option>
    <?php }
    ?>
</select>

<br/><br/>
Select Song : <br/><br/>
<input type="file" name="song"/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload"/>
<br/>
</form>
```

Comment: On behalf of the SO-community: Welcome, and thank you for your answer! Perhaps you could improve it a bit though, and explain to the question-asker what the difference is in your code and why this is necessary?